formatting numbers in ConTeXt
I don't know if this question is asked before. If so please show me the link.
With LaTeX, siunitx do the job.
I type    \num{12545} the result is 12 545.
How to do the same thing with ConTeXt?

The \spaceddigits command is what you're looking for:
\let\spaceddigitsseparator=\thinspace

\startTEXpage[offset=1ex, width=2in, align=middle]
    \spaceddigits{1234567.890}
\stopTEXpage



Thank you. this command is not defined in the site or even in context commands. Can't wait for full documentation! For me, as a beginner, it's hard to find my way around.

@Aviroum Anyone can edit the Wiki, so I've just added it now. More generally, you can also look at the Units manual (which unfortunately cannot auto-space the digits for you).
